# What kind of significance tests can I apply on before/after data that involves proportions?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data, mcnemar-test

I am trying to determine whether there is statistical significance from two groups of data. I have the data in terms of counts and proportions or percentages.

There are two columns which show the frequency of visits to their personal trainer based on receiving notifications about their fitness.

There are different notification severity categories labelled as "severe", "elevated", "moderate" and "low requirement". The "before" period is the baseline with "suppressed" notifications, which means that we the investigators are the only ones that know of the notification status during this time. There is an "after" period where now people are receiving these notifications. There are a different number of notifications sent out in each period for each notification category.

Below I show you the raw counts of visits to their personal trainers for each period.

|  | BEFORE | AFTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| low requirement | 2311 | 2400 |
| moderate | 1344 | 1523 |
| elevated | 264 | 277 |
| severe | 28 | 78 |

I want to see whether the notifications had an impact on the number of visits to their personal trainers.

EDIT:

So after speaking to @BruceET I understand that applying tests on percentages is not appropriate. I may benefit from using a contingency table for each category.

Below I show an example of a 2x2 contingency table for the severe category:

|  | BEFORE | AFTER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Visit | 28 | 78 |
| No Visit | 300 | 450 |

I'm wondering whether I can apply a chi-square test or a McNemars test to determine whether there is a statistical difference in the after period...

Comment: Generally, percentages are not useful for this kind of analysis. (7 Heads in 10 tosses doesn't mean a coin is biased for Heads, but 70 Heads in 100 tosses is pretty good evidence of that.) Consider making a table of counts from which the percentages were derived: responses vs. nonresponses, before vs. after, and for each of the four categories.

Comment: ... Consider that 5.34 and 6.9 may be significantly different for Moderate, while 6.33 and 12 may not be significant for Severe. Perhaps a chi-squared test for independence would tell you some of what you want to know, and _ad hoc_ chi-squared tests just for one of the categories at a time might tell you more.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see your points... would plotting both lines from each group and applying a goodness of fit measured by chi^2 be considered ok to do?

Comment: First, you have to decide what you want to know. Then look at various chi-squared 'contingency' tables, their analyses, and what info is provided. Then design the table(s) you need. // Give row, column, and grand totals for Respondents and non. Make sure all subjects are accounted for.

Comment: Ok, got it, I'm thinking that a 2x2 contingency table would probably reveal the proportions element of my data. I'm assuming that because I am testing a before and after period that a McNemars test might be appropriate?

Comment: What kind of interpretation are you trying to get at? Trying to conclude that the notifications cause visits? If so, this may be the wrong study design, if you do not know what would have happened without the notifications (assuming that it would have been no change from the baseline period may not be a good assumption, in many health-type interventions there are usually massive improvements from baseline even if not intervention is done).